# Search for a few hundred filenames in a few hundred log files

Tags: multithreading, bash, grep

I would like to efficiently search through a few hundred log files for ~200 filenames.

I can easily do this using `grep`'s `-f` directive and putting the needle(s) in a file.

However, there are a few problems:

- I'm interested in doing this efficiently, as in [How to use grep efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200591/how-to-use-grep-efficiently)
- I want to know all the matches for *each* search term (i.e. filename) in all log files separately. `grep -f` would match as it finds needles in each file.
- I would like to know when a filename is not matched anywhere.

2.7 i7 MBP w/ 16gb of ram

Using `grep -ron -f needle *` gives me:

```
access_log-2013-01-01:88298:google
access_log-2013-01-01:88304:google
access_log-2013-01-01:88320:test
access_log-2013-01-01:88336:google
access_log-2013-01-02:396244:test
access_log-2013-01-02:396256:google
access_log-2013-01-02:396262:google
```

where `needle` contains:

```
google
test
```

The problems here is the whole directory is searched for any match from `needle` and the process is single-threaded so it takes forever. There's also no explicit information as to whether it fails to find a match.

Comment: Do any of the filenames contain spaces? Also, will there be times when a filename is appended to other text or will it always be separated by whitespace/start of line/end of line?

Comment: how does the output of this script looks like ?

Comment: @Desidero filenames don't contain spaces. Filenames may be appended to other text. Think /foor/bar/baz/needle.txt

Comment: @michael not sure I follow.

Comment: @kayaker243 , assuming you have a solution for this problem , how does the output look like . give us an example of input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about combining `grep` and `find` in a bash script?

```
for needle in $(cat needles.txt); do
    echo $needle
    matches=$(find . -type f -exec grep -nH -e $needle {} +)
    if [[ 0 == $? ]] ; then
        if [[ -z "$matches" ]] ; then
            echo "No matches found"
        else
            echo "$matches"
        fi
    else
        echo "Search failed / no matches"
    fi
    echo
done
```

`needles.txt` contains a list of your target filenames.

To read the needles (which now can contain spaces) line-by-line from
the file, use this version:

```
cat needles.txt | while read needle ; do
    echo $needle
    matches=$(find . -type f -exec grep -nH -e "$needle" {} +)
    if [[ 0 == $? ]] ; then
        if [[ -z "$matches" ]] ; then
            echo "No matches found"
        else
            echo "$matches"
        fi
    else
        echo "Search failed / no matches"
    fi
    echo
done
```

If you do the combination with `xargs`, the error code $? is no longer zero even on success.
This may be less safe, but works for me:

```
cat needles.txt | while read needle ; do
  echo $needle
  matches=$(find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P2 grep -nH -e "$needle")
  if [[ -z "$matches" ]] ; then
        echo "No matches found"
  else
        echo "$matches"
  fi
  echo
done
```

Comment: Thanks! I modified it slightly to use xargs to spread grep over 8 processes.  `matches=$(find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P8 grep -nH -E $needle)`. This appears to work. However, it turns out I do need to match for spaces - the term I want to search is actually `GET /term/`. 

Including a backslash before the term in needles.txt fails, seeming to exit execution. Quoting `$needle` seems to prevent evaluation of `$needle`. Any suggestion?

Comment: @kayaker243 Can you adapt the version in the edit to your needs? Thanks for pointing out the parallelization with xargs, that is new to me.

Comment: no, my bash skills aren't up to the challenge of dealing with whitespace in this context :(

Comment: Does the second version above not work with needles that contain spaces? Just put `GET /term/` on a dingle line in needles.txt.

Comment: Yes, putting needles with spaces on their own lines causes the script to die.

Comment: For me with the xargs call included the `if [[ 0 == $? ]] ` no longer worked correctly. Does the third snippet above work for you?

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention I had to comment that portion out.

Comment: @kayaker: Can you post your current code and a simple test case that fails?

Answer (score 1):

To determine which needles no longer have matches, you can take the output from grep and:

1. Use awk or something similar to extract just the matched strings to a separate file.
2. Concatenate that needles file to that file
3. Do `sort --uniq filename -o temp1`
4. Concatenate the needles file to temp1
5. Do `sort temp1 -o temp2`
6. `uniq -u temp2 > temp3`

temp3 will contain the needles that are no longer used.

There might be a more concise way to do that. Steps 1 through 3 get a list of the unique needles that are found in the files.

Say your needles file contains:

```
google
foo
bar
```

And grep finds foo and bar in multiple files, but doesn't find google. Step 1 would create a file like:

```
foo
bar
bar
foo
foo
bar
foo
```

`sort --uniq` will create:

```
foo
bar
```

Concatenating the needles file gives

```
foo
bar
google
foo
bar
```

Sorting gives:

```
bar
bar
foo
foo
google
```

And the final `uniq -u` command will output a single line:

```
google
```