# How to index text files to improve grep time

Tags: linux, indexing, grep, full-text-search

I have a large number of text files I need to grep through on a regular basis.

There are ~230,000 files amounting to around 15GB of data.

I've read the following threads:

- [How to use grep efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200591/how-to-use-grep-efficiently)
- [How to use grep with large (millions) number of files to search for string and get result in few minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694379/how-to-use-grep-with-large-millions-number-of-files-to-search-for-string-and-g)

The machine I'll be grepping on is an Intel Core i3 (i.e. dual-core), so I can't parallelize to any great extent. The machine is running Ubuntu and I'd prefer to do everything via the command line.

Instead of running a bog-standard grep each time, is there any way I can either index or tag the contents of the text files to improve searching?

Comment: Do the files have data that you can meaningfully index on? If you can do that then you can write anything you want to operate on that index. I don't know of off-the-shelf tools for this though.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. The data in the files is human-readable text. I've edited my explanation to read "...is there a way I can either index or tag the contents...". I think I should have used the word "tag" rather than "index" originally.

Comment: Sounds like it's time to put that data into a database

Comment: @glennjackman How would I go about putting this into a database? What tools would I use? MySQL, or a type of database specific to this text-based problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) as a replacement for grep? It should be in the Ubuntu repositories. I had a similar problem as yours, and ag is really much faster than grep for most regex searches. There are some differences in syntax and features, but that would only matter if you had special grep-specific needs.