# Grepping for certain extensions with an arbitrary depth

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

```
grep -r "print " */*/*/*/*/*.py */*/*/*/*.py */*/*/*.py */*/*.py
```

I want to look for all the ocurrences of `"print "` in all `.py` files in subdirectories inside my current directory. I came up with the above command and it works, but I'd like to find some sort of way to have an arbitrary depth because some of my files are on a depth of 3, others on 4 and others on even higher depths.

I'm pretty sure I can maybe use `find` and then pipe, but I'm not quite sure how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On bash and zsh you can use `**`:

```
grep "print " **/*.py
```

If the double star is not available on your shell of choice, then you can use `xargs` like:

```
find . -regex ".*\.py" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "print "
```

Comment: For bash you need to set `shopt -s globstar`.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `globstar` without the `t`. I edited the comment. It also requires bash v4 or higher.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `find` with `-exec`

```
find -type f -name '*.py' -exec grep -H 'print ' {} \;
```

---

For better performance, use `find` with `xargs`

```
find -type f -name '*.py' -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'print '
```

Comment: No, for better performance use `find -type f -name '*.py' -exec grep -H 'print ' {} +` (with the `+` at the end!)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Ohh! I didn't know that option and may be third alternative. But I read somewhere that `xargs` approach is most effective. Correct me if I'am wrong. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I doubt the `xargs` method will be the most effective. It will have a pipe and a fork overhead compared to the `find -type f -name '*.py' -exec grep -H 'print ' {} +` method.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Please refer to [accepted answer of this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200591/how-to-use-grep-efficiently). And if you still disagree, some reference would be helpful.

Comment: After several naive testings it seems the `xargs` way wins. I've edited my answer accordingly. Thank you again for pointing this out!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf You're welcome! I had not tested it by myself and was relying on expert opinions and test results. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 2):

No need for a pipe.

```
find some/dir -name '*.py' -exec grep -H "print " {} \;
```

Comment: This is highly inefficient, since `grep` will be executed once per each python file. For big directory trees, it matters.

Comment: Thank you very much, problem with that solution (and also the one by @jkshah) is that they don't list the file name and location before the print thing.

Answer (score 1):

If your `grep` supports the `--include` option, use it:

```
grep -R --include='*.py' 'print ' .
```

<strike>That's definitely the best option here.</strike> The `xargs` option in the other answers might be better as it uses multithreading in an efficient way.

---

Funny: to tell whether your `grep` handles this option, you can of course `man grep` then search in there for the string `--include` with the keystrokes `/--include` or you can:

```
man grep | grep -- --include
```

or

```
grep --help | grep -- --include
```

---

Otherwise, since no one mentionned the `-exec ... +` way of using `find`, here it is:

```
find -type f -name '*.py' -exec grep -H 'print ' {} +
```

but that's not as good as the `grep --include` way. But as said before, the multithreading capabilities of the methods with `xargs` should perform better.