# multiple greps going in uninterruptible state

Tags: bash, grep, xargs

so I have around 30 folders & each folder contains ~ 75 text files. They are actually BGP dumps taken from [routeviews](https://archive.routeviews.org/)
The total amount of data sums upto ~ 480 GBs & now I've to grep a list of IPs from it. So I used normal grep & looped over the IP list, & then looped over datasets, but it was too slow.
I came across this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200591/how-to-use-grep-efficiently) on using grep using xargs & it worked well. I timed the results, it was ~ 7 sec for normal grep & ~ 1.5 sec for // grep for 1 folder.(using 24 instances at once) 
Now here's the problem, when I did this in nested loop over IP list & datasets, it worked well for starting folders but eventually the multiple greps went in `uninterruptible state`, I don't know why...
The command I used for grep is - 
`find ./ -name "rib.${YYMM}${DATE}.${TIME}*" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P24 grep ${prefix} | wc -l >> ${TIME}` 
where `${YYMM}` , `${DATE}` , `${TIME}` is to identify files & `${prefix}` is the iterable variable for prefixes to be grepped.
Sample naming convention for files -

> rib.20191201.0200_chicago
> rib.20191230.2000_chile
> rib.20191215.1400_sydney

[image: Here is the screenshot of htop] 
Specs : I'm using a Ubuntu 16.04.2 server, with 20 v-CPU & 50 GB RAM, definitely not overload on them according to htop. 
Is there any workaround for this?
Since I got huge IP list, so even 1 sec makes a big difference in long run

Comment: You are aware that `grep` matches a `regex` and that `.` matches any character, not a dot?  Are you interested in `grep` output, or just the count? Why not `grep -c`? (I also think you could try `-n3`) `is the iterable variable for prefixes` So there any many prefixes? Why not filter all prefixes in one go (assuming I/O is the slowest)? `went in uninterruptible state` Are you sure that is not caused by waiting for I/O?

Comment: Yep, I'm aware about the regex, but in my case it doesn't matter as I'll either get a exact match or not. I'm more interested only in count. The file format is just IP <some whole number> <some whole number> ....

Comment: There are about ~ 5000 prefixes, is it possible to filter them at one go?

Comment: `is it possible to filter them at one go?` Write an `awk` script. Would be slower then grep, but reading same files 5000 times will be way slower. Even `grep -of <(paterns) | sort | uniq -c` could be faster then I/O.

Comment: Could you hint me a little with awk?

Comment: `seq 100 | awk 'BEGIN{ pattern[0]="1"; pattern[1]="2" }  { for (i in pattern) if ($0 ~ pattern[i]) count[i]++ } END{ for (i in count) print i " occured " count[i] " times" }'`

Comment: One last thing, should I run them parallelly with `nohup cmd &` or simply in foreground? Which one is better optimized?

Comment: "better optimized" depends on your hardware's capabilities. Typically you'll gain from a small amount of parallelism but too much will slow things down as processes start contending for scarce/shared resources (like disk head position and scheduling); hence why things like `xargs -P` exist.

Comment: That said, even if you do want to run something in the background in a way that survives the terminal it's in closing, there's barely ever a good reason to use `nohup`. bash's built-in `disown` and redirection of stdin/stdout/stderr and you have everything nohup does in native shell.

Comment: And I fully agree with the prior comments that suggest giving up grep in favor of a one-pass approach.

Comment: If you're overwhelming, say, an NFS server all your files are stored on, you get processes waiting for syscalls to return, and that's exactly what D state _is_.

Comment: Actually I said `nohup` because it's my university's server. I've to connect to their VPN every time before I can SSH into it

Comment: I did `ulimit -aH` & it shows `open files` limit as `1048576`. Will increasing the limit on open files have any significant effect on performance of grep? The max limit is `5133157`

Comment: No impact at all. That limit tells you when attempts to open files will fail. If you aren't getting errors caused by failures, changing it won't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I figured a way out !
I wrote a bash script to upload the whole 480GB database to mongoDB.
It takes significant amount of time, but it is helpful for me in long run when I got a lot of prefixes to search. I indexed it on the basis of `prefixes` & boom!
Now I can search a prefix in less than *200 milliseconds*
which was *7 seconds* in traditional grep
& ~ *1.5 seconds* in grep with xargs
Wrote another shell script to loop over prefixes & it converted the computation of days into minutes
**Sample code:**
To upload:
`mongoimport -d DB_name -c C_name --type csv --file "F_name" --headerline`
To index:
`mongo --quiet --eval "db.getCollection('C_name').createIndex({PREFIX:1});" DB_name`
To search:
`mongo --quiet --eval "db.getCollection('C_name').find({ PREFIX: '117.193.0.0/20' }).count();" DB_name`